# WPF TextBox with word suggestions

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete

I would like to have a WPF **TextBox** that will suggest words as I type. I don't want a functionality that **ComboBox** has where it just fills it for you. Here is the example what I need: For example I am typing a text into my TextBox: 
"I am going to school at 12:00PM" Say in my collection I have the word school. as I start typing "s" it should suggest the word school or any words in the collection that starts with "s". 
Is there a control that is already created? Or someone can direct me to the correct path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In codeproject site there is an article "WPF Autocomplete Textbox Control"
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26535/WPF-Autocomplete-Textbox-Control

I think it may be helpful for you.